Simple limit of a function
I want the solve the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}-\cos{(x^2)}}{x^2\sin{(x)}-x\tan{(x^2)}}\,.
$$
The path I would like to use is Taylor expansion of both numerator and denominator. Do you have any suggestion?

The feel is that this is a textbook exercise. And on a quick glance I would say l'Hospital reguires 3 derivations.... I feel that this one is made to force students to use Taylor expansions.

Yes, you can use series expansion to solve this. It goes like this
$$\sqrt{1+x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{n} x^{4n}\qquad\cos(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{4n}$$
$$x^2\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+3}\qquad x\tan(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{T_{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{4n+3}$$
Where $T_n$ is the $n$th tangent number. We'll only really need the first few terms of these expansions, so let's write
$$\sqrt{1+x^4} = 1+\frac12 x^4 + O(x^8)\qquad\cos(x^2) = 1-\frac12 x^4+O(x^8)$$
$$x^2\sin(x) = x^3 - \frac16 x^5+O(x^7)\qquad x\tan(x^2) = x^3+\frac13x^7+O(x^{11})$$
Thus
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^4}-\cos(x^2)}{x^2\sin(x)-x\tan(x)}
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\dfrac12 x^4\right) - \left(1-\dfrac12 x^4\right) + O(x^8)}{\left(x^3 - \dfrac16 x^5\right) - \left(x^3+\dfrac13x^7\right)+ O(x^7)}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^4 + O(x^8)}{-\dfrac16 x^5 + O(x^7)}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1 + O(x^4)}{-\dfrac16 x + O(x^3)} = \pm\infty\\
\end{aligned}$$
We can plot the graph of $f(x) \equiv \dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^4}-\cos(x^2)}{x^2\sin(x)-x\tan(x)}$ for a sanity check and observe it behaves as expected

